# How to use .env to store a JSON key for use with JWT?

Tags: node.js, json, environment-variables, jwt, google-apis-explorer

I am using google analytics api and need to pass in a json key I was given to make a JWT. However, instead of accessing the key from my .json file, I want my key information to be stored in my .env file.

My struggle is that my .env variable cannot be read and I keep getting errors about the information not being valid etc.

here is an example key that is structured like mine:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "id",
  "private_key_id": "id",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nddaasdfasdfasdafasfadsafsdafadsafasdfasdfasdfads\nasdfasdfasdafsdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfd\nasdfasdfasdfasfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf\nddaasdfasdfasdafasfadsafsdafadsafasdfasdfasdfads\nasdfasdfasdafsdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfd\nasdfasdfasdfasfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf\nddaasdfasdfasdafasfadsafsdafadsafasdfasdfasdfads\nasdfasdfasdafsdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfd\nasdfasdfasdfasfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf\nddaasdfasdfasdafasfadsafsdafadsafasdfasdfasdfads\nasdfasdfasdafsdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfd\nasdfasdfasdfasfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "email",
  "client_id": "number",
  "auth_uri": "uri",
  "token_uri": "uri",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "url",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "url"
}
```

here is how it is written in my .env file:

```
CREDS='{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "id",
  "private_key_id": "id",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nddaasdfasdfasdafasfadsafsdafadsafasdfasdfasdfads\nasdfasdfasdafsdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfd\nasdfasdfasdfasfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf\nddaasdfasdfasdafasfadsafsdafadsafasdfasdfasdfads\nasdfasdfasdafsdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfd\nasdfasdfasdfasfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf\nddaasdfasdfasdafasfadsafsdafadsafasdfasdfasdfads\nasdfasdfasdafsdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfd\nasdfasdfasdfasfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf\nddaasdfasdfasdafasfadsafsdafadsafasdfasdfasdfads\nasdfasdfasdafsdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasfd\nasdfasdfasdfasfadsfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "email",
  "client_id": "number",
  "auth_uri": "uri",
  "token_uri": "uri",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "url",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "url"
}'
```

Here is the code where I am  using it:

```
const keysEnvVar = process.env['CREDS'];

const keys = JSON.parse(keysEnvVar);

const authClient = new google.auth.JWT( email, auth.fromJSON(keys), null, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
```

one hunch is that the "private_key" value isn't written properly and that it is screwing things up but I am honestly not sure what to do.

Thanks for reading

Comment: ENV vars aren't the best place for JSON objects. Why not put it in it's own file and require() it? Without including the specific errors you are encountering, everyone offering advice will just be guessing.

Comment: you can see this link and use .env file https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late, but for others who get stuck on the same error *(Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line)* can use below '\n' for each new line and after that use following command to extract the keys from .env file as it should be.

```
process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')
```

**Example:**

```
const keysEnvVar = process.env['CREDS'].replace(/\\n/g, '\n');
```